# Generating HTML tables where more items have one key asnd must fit on the same row

Tags: python, html, django, web

In Django, I am trying to generate a table. The first column is a timestamp. The next 5 columns need to be filled with my data.

However, my data table has 5 entries for each related timestamp. How can I put this data into my table with the correct headers?

The data entries are all seperate objects within Django..

The table has multiple rows with each their own timestamp, and their 5 corresponding data entries.

Is it possible to make this in the template layer, or view layer?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>date</th>
        {% for sensor in sensors %}
        <th>{{ sensor }}</th>
        {%  endfor %}
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
    {% for stamp in stamps %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ stamp.stamp|date:"D d N H:i" }}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'survey:TimestampDetailed' stamp.id %}">Bekijk Detail</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: What do your models look like? What are `stamps` and `sensors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling all this really complicated data in Django's template layer, this ought to be solved using the viewlayer.

First you create a new array, and seed it's table headers

```
table = ["header 1", "header 2"]
```

For each individual row you will add your data. The data I requested as a single datetime, followed by measurements. This equated to the following code

```
for x in range(0, len(timestamps)):
    table.append(timestamp)
    for datapoint in data:
        table.append(datapoint)
```

You can then iterate through it in django's template layer.

```
<table>
    {% for row in table %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
        <td>{{item}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You can add some custom if/else statements for headers and that kind of thing.